# Read MAX values from CSV file without overwriting the existing values of the new CSV file

Tags: powershell

my problem is I have a folder with an unspecified number of CSV files.
The MAX value of each CSV file should be read from this folder and the read MAX value should be written to a new CSV file.
Here is my current script unfortunately I can only read single files.

```
Import-CSV 'Folder-Path' -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | sort {[decimal]$_.Value} -Descending | select -F 1 | export-csv 'Folder-Path' -Delimiter ";" -NoType -Encoding Default -Append #>
```

Also, the script should not overwrite the MAX values in the new CSV file
and only the MAX values that are not yet in the new CSV file.

The CSV files from which the MAX value is to be read partly look like the following and contain 1000+ rows:

```
 "Series"; "Time"; "Value"
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:24";56
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:26";59
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:28";60
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:30";60
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:32";57
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:34";58
 "Total Session Number";"2020-01-15 01:36";58
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
"Series"; "Time"; "Value"
"Total Session Number"; "2020-01-15 17:36"; "197"
```

Because the CSV files are not always the same `(example: file 1 is called session_access, file 2 is called session_number.  "Series" name is for file 1 'session_access' and for file 2 "Series" name is 'session_number'`), 
to compare the existing MAX-values with the series name and the time.
This I had considered to solve with the help of an array or something similar.
Unfortunately I would not know how to do that.

Example files I use for testing:

First test file :

```
"Series"; "Time"; "Value" 
"Total Session Number"; "2020-01-25 01:00";59
```

Second test file:

```
"Series"; "Time"; "Value"
"FactoryTest"; "2020-01-24 01:00";0
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: How would you identify MAX values already written to your resulting CSV file? You'd need to have an identifier. You may include the source file name to your resulting CSV file to be able to eliminate doublettes and avoid data to be overwritten. It may be necessary to import the already existing CSV file to able to update it properly.

Comment: I would identify the max value that already exists by the series name and time (date). I had considered solving this with the help of an array or something similar. Unfortunately I would not know how to do that.

Comment: If you have information helpful to understand your challenge you should update your actual question.   ... you like to distinguish the valuse by their series name? In your example they are all the same!?!  ;-)  you may post some example content of the csv files and maybe the names of those CSV files as well to show what you're talking about. (Please format those example data as code as well)

Comment: Okay, I'll do it.

Comment: Are the values the third value in each columns?

Comment: the value is in the "Value" column

Comment: I have read this problem a few times. I still don’t get what the problem is as your code appears to do what you want. Are you wanting to retrieve the row with the max value of `Value` per unique value of `Series` because your code does not do that. I don’t understand the not overwriting requirement unless you are writing all output to one single CSV.

Comment: the outputs should all be saved in a CSV file.
With my script I can only read single CSV files and not several at once.

Comment: So you want to read 1000s of files for the one row that has the maximum value? If so, you can just run your code without `Export-Csv` and store its output in a variable. Then check that variable for the maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm still pretty unsure if I got what you're actually trying to do. Let's try it anyway:

Because you're trying obviously to mix different data sets you have to do a little trick. Assumed the column with the data you want to put in the "series" category all start with the word "session" you can try to do it like this:

```
$Directory = 'Folder-Path'
$Result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter 'session*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $InputData = Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter ';' |
            Sort-Object -Property {[decimal]$_.Value} -Descending |
                Select-Object -First 1 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Series = $InputData.Series
            Time = $InputData.Time
            Value = $InputData.Value
        }
    }
$Result
$Result | Export-Csv -Path 'path to your results CSV file' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

First you specify the path you want to work in. Then you collect all CSV files and import them with Import-Csv. You sort the data from the CSV file for your desired value and pick the first one.
Now you create a new data set where you add the source file name to be able to identify where the source data come from. And you "convert" the different "session" thing data to the data cell "Series".

Is it that what you needed?

Of course you can output the data in any way you want or put some further steps to export them to a new CSV file or whatever. ;-)

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the help. Whenever I try to run the code on myself, I always get an error.  Then where is the "result" exported to?

Comment: In the output I get the source file output. This is not needed but the "Session" name should be displayed like "Total Session Number". Unfortunately I can't get the output into a new CSV file.

Comment: I cannot see your screen. So you will have to be more specific about the error.. ;-) In my code suggestion the result is not exported. If you wnat to specify your requirements please update your question with detailed information.  ...  and of course you are allowed to change my code suggestion to your needs.

Comment: Error Message: Select-Object : Property "Session*" cannot be found.
At line:9 char:35
+ ...          Series = $InputData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Session*
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Series=Online...:18; Value=202}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: How can I export the result from the code to a new CSV file?

Comment: Could you please post a few lines of the actual source CSV files? What's the header for the "Series" category in your CSV source files?

Comment: I can only give you a few lines as an example because there are about 20 different files.
First test file : 
"Series"; "Time"; "Value"
"Total Session Number"; "2020-01-25 01:00";59

Second test file:
 "Series"; "Time"; "Value"
"FactoryTest"; "2020-01-24 01:00";0

Comment: That's what I said - a few lines. But you should add it formatted as code to your original question.  Thanks.

Comment: OK. I understood something almost completely else before. Chahnged the code accordingly.

Comment: Now it works. How can I write the result to a new CSV file ?

Comment: You use [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) ... just like you did in the code you posted. ;-)  ... added the code in my example.